# How to write new pooling layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I'd like to write RMS pooling layer in TensorFlow. This is like `tf.nn.avg_pool()` but instead of doing simple average it should calculate RMS average.

I'd like to write this using numpy initially; I don't care about it running on GPU (but later I would like to write a GPU version)

Comment: you can use `tf.py_func` for numpy implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
tf.sqrt(tf.nn.avg_pool(tf.square(value - \
     tf.reduce_mean(value, reduction_indices=[0, 1, 2])),
     <ksize>, <strides>, <padding>))
```

Note that l_2 pooling is commonly used and not RMS pooling.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I think I mean L2 pooling, it is just called "RMS" in the code I'm working with.  This looks about right: `tf.sqrt(tf.nn.avg_pool(tf.square(value)))` I'll remember the reduce_mean trick though.

Comment: Why should we use `value - tf.reduce_mean(value, reduction_indices=[0, 1, 2])` here?